# Ansible : Module not found when using collection

Tags: ansible, roles

I'm working with Ansible, I made a collection with some roles, all is working flawlessly, I can use my roles etc. until recently.

I tried to use the hashivault_write and hashivault_read modules (https://pypi.org/project/ansible-modules-hashivault/) but it seems it's not working when I used them in roles **from** my collection.

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'hashivault_write'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/xxxx/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/xx/roles/roles/postfix/tasks/opendkim.yml': line 92, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

## Write opendkim private key in vault
- name: "Write in vault"
  ^ here
```

When the **exact** same role is used outside the collection (straight from ansible `roles/` folder) I don't have this issue. I guess the problem is not the module installation because it's working from outside the collection.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating source code of Ansible collection and module resolution, I understood that inside of a collection a module or action without a fqdn are resolved locally on that collection or their name is appended to 'ansible.buildin' fqdn.

To solve this impasse there are 2 solutions:

- Add the 'ansible.legacy' fqdn and this would resolve to "legacy" modules installed via pip
- create a 'meta/runtime.yml' in your collection and add a redirect to the "legacy" module

  ```
  ---
  plugin_routing:
    modules:
      hashivault_write:
        redirect: ansible.legacy.hashivault_write
  ```

Comment: `module:` should be `modules:`